# Strange behavior in json.net: why is a null JToken replaced with a non-null value?

Tags: c#, null, json.net

This using json.net (C#). Not sure why JToken is not null.

```
var obj = new JObject();
obj["field1"] = null;
var token = obj["field1"];

Console.WriteLine(token == null); // false 
Console.WriteLine(token.ToString() == ""); // true

Console.WriteLine(token.Type == JTokenType.Null); // true
```

Comment: Json.NET never actually allows a `null` value in the `JToken` hierarchy.  Instead it replaces nulls with a *non-null `JValue`* with [`JValue.Type`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_Type.htm) equal to [`JTokenType.Null`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenType.htm).

Comment: See [Newtonsoft Json.Net serialize JObject doesn't ignore nulls, even with the right settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29259032/3744182) or [Issue with JSON null handling in Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31141975/3744182) or [Null-coalescing operator returning null for properties of dynamic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29053805/3744182) for details.

Answer (score 10):

This is by design.

Json.NET never allows an actual null `JToken` value to appear in a `JToken` hierarchy, either as an `JArray` member or a `JProperty` value.  Instead, if applications code attempts to set or add a `null` token, it gets replaced with a *non-null `JValue`* with [`JValue.Type`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_Type.htm) equal to [`JTokenType.Null`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenType.htm).  This replacement occurs in, e.g., [`JContainer.EnsureParentToken(JToken item, bool skipParentCheck)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JContainer.cs#L322):

```
    internal JToken EnsureParentToken(JToken item, bool skipParentCheck)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return JValue.CreateNull();
        }
```

As well as [`JProperty.Value`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JProperty.cs#L153):

```
    public JToken Value
    {
        set
        {
            CheckReentrancy();

            JToken newValue = value ?? JValue.CreateNull();
```

I believe Newtonsoft does this to capture the difference between the following two JSON objects:

```
{
   "field1": null
}
```

And the empty object:

```
{ }
```

In the first case, the property `"field1"` is present with a `null` JSON value.  In the second case, the property `"field1"` is not present.  Linq-to-JSON represents the first case with a null-type `JValue` rather than having `JProperty.Value` actually *be null*.  It likely does this because if it did not, `object["field1"]` would return `null` in both cases, making them harder to distinguish.  (Unlike `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `JObject` does not throw a `KeyNotFoundException` when attempting to access the value of a non-existent property.  Instead, [`JObject.Item[String]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) returns a null `JValue` for the value of a missing key.)

Your code, `obj["field1"] = null;`, creates a JSON object of the first form, which you can see if you examine the value of `obj.ToString()`.  Thus `obj["field1"]` returns non-null

If you do not need to distinguish between missing and null-valued properties, you could introduce an extension method to check for a null value such as the one of the ones from *[Checking for empty/null JToken in a JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24066400/3744182)* or *[Issue with JSON null handling in Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31141527/3744182)*.