# JTokenType for null string JValue does not match other null JValues

Tags: c#, json.net

I was comparing JTokens with JToken.DeepEquals() for test code when I encountered a failing test that troubled me:

```
testResult: { "str": null, "int": 1 } // Child of a larger JObject
expectedResult: { "str": null, "int": 1 } //Parsed from a string with JToken.Parse()
if (!JToken.DeepEquals(testResult, expectedResult)) return TestFailed
```

I expected these tokens to be equal. I tinkered around with the failing test for a while, and found the failure was a result of `v1._valueType != v2._valueType` when comparing the "str" JValues. The type was JTokenType.String for the testResult, and JTokenType.Null for the parsed expectedResult.

I was eventually able to reproduce the issue with the following test:

```
  string nullStr = null;
  JToken nullToken = null;

  var b0 = JToken.Equals(nullStr, nullToken); // True

  var jObj = new JObject()
  {
    ["str"] = nullStr, // null
    ["tkn"] = nullToken, // null
    ["ltrl"] = null
  };

  var b1 = JToken.DeepEquals(jObj["str"], jObj["tkn"]); // False
  var b2 = JToken.DeepEquals(jObj["tkn"], jObj["ltrl"]); // True
  var b3 = JToken.DeepEquals(jObj["str"], jObj["ltrl"]); // False

  var t0 = jObj["str"].Type; // String
  var t1 = jObj["tkn"].Type; // Null
  var t2 = jObj["ltrl"].Type; // Null

  var parsedJObj = JToken.Parse(jObj.ToString());

  var b4 = JToken.DeepEquals(parsedJObj["str"], parsedJObj["tkn"]); // True
  var b5 = JToken.DeepEquals(parsedJObj["tkn"], parsedJObj["ltrl"]); // True
  var b6 = JToken.DeepEquals(parsedJObj["str"], parsedJObj["ltrl"]); // True

  var t3 = parsedJObj["str"].Type; // Null
  var t4 = parsedJObj["tkn"].Type; // Null
  var t5 = parsedJObj["ltrl"].Type; // Null

  Console.WriteLine($@"null string = null token: {b0}
jObj[str] = jObj[tkn]: {b1}
jObj[tkn] = jObj[ltrl]: {b2}
jObj[str] = jObj[ltrl]: {b3}
jObj[str].Type: {t0}
jObj[tkn].Type: {t1}
jObj[ltrl].Type: {t2}
parsedJObj[str] = parsedJObj[tkn]: {b4}
parsedJObj[tkn] = parsedJObj[ltrl]: {b5}
parsedJObj[str] = parsedJObj[ltrl]: {b6}
parsedJObj[str].Type: {t3}
parsedJObj[tkn].Type: {t4}
parsedJObj[ltrl].Type: {t5}");
```

It appears to me there is a special case for assigning a string null literal, is this intended behavior?
I am using .NET 7.0 and the Newtonsoft.Json package v13.0.3

Comment: As explained in [Strange behavior in json.net: why is a null JToken replaced with a non-null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777115/3744182), a `null` value is always replaced with a non-null `JValue` of type `JTokenType.Null` when added to a `JObject` or `JArray`. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in *[Strange behavior in json.net: why is a null JToken replaced with a non-null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777115/3744182)*, it is expected behavior that, when you try to add a `null` value to a `JObject` or `JArray`, it will be replaced with a non-null `JValue` of type `JTokenType.Null`.

However, it is surprising that

```
var jObj = new JObject()
{
    ["str"] = nullStr, // null
}
```

Results in a token with type `JTokenType.String`.  I believe this can be explained as follows.  You are using the [dictionary index initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer) to populate your `JObject`.  Now, the dictionary type that [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) implements is `IDictionary<string, JToken>`.  But `string` is not a `JToken`, so how were you able to initialize it?  Well, it turns out that there is an [implicit operator](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Implicit_29.htm) to convert a `string` to `JToken`.  And, as can be seen from the reference source [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/01e1759cac40d8154e47ed0e11c12a9d42d2d0ff/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L1781) and [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/01e1759cac40d8154e47ed0e11c12a9d42d2d0ff/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JValue.cs#L166), this always returns a `JValue` of type `JTokenType.String`, even for `null` strings:

> ```
> public static implicit operator JToken(string? value)
> {
>     return new JValue(value);
> }
>
> public JValue(string? value)
>     : this(value, JTokenType.String)
> {
> }
> ```

This explains the inconsistency you are seeing.

If you don't like this behavior, you could use a constructor or setter that takes an `object` rather than a `JToken`, such as the [`JProperty(string, object)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty__ctor_1.htm) constructor:

```
var jObj = new JObject()
{
    new JProperty("str", nullStr),
    new JProperty("tkn", nullToken),
    new JProperty("ltrl", null),
};
```

By using this constructor the implicit operator is not invoked and all three values end up being of type `JTokenType.Null`.

Notes:

- There is no `JToken.Equals()` static method, there is only [`JToken.DeepEquals()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_DeepEquals.htm).  So when you write `JToken.Equals(jObj["str"], jObj["tkn"])` you are actually calling the base class static method [`object.Equals(object, object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-8.0#system-object-equals(system-object-system-object)).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rx4TlU).

Comment: Wonderful explanation! I figured it had something to do with the implicit operator, I'll use the JProperty constructor instead.

Comment: @MatthewTenczar - Glad to have helped. If the question is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147532).