# When `JToken?` is null?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Iterating through `json` Im using `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```cs
var jObject = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken?> superior in jObject) {
...
}
```

As you can see above, JObject implements `IEnumerable<KeyValueString<string, JToken?>>`. But i can find no cases when `JToken` is null in enumeration.

I tryied this:

```json
{

}
```

```json
{
   "A": { }
}
```

```json
{
   "A": ""
}
```

```json
{
    "A": null
}
```

...and its always not null.
So why then enumerator is using `JToken?`?

Comment: [Related, but not exactly a duplicate IMO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51776584/3094533)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will never get a null `JToken`. As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777115/5133585) says, Newtonsoft JSON is designed to not allow any null values. Every null value is converted to a `JValue` instance with the `Null` type.

Just to be more convincing, see how `GetEnumerator` is implemented in the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#L713):

```
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, JToken?>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (JProperty property in _properties)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, JToken?>(property.Name, property.Value);
        }
    }
```

and `JProperty.Value` is of type `JToken`, not `JToken?`.

I suspect the reason why it implements `IDictionary<string, JToken?>` and not `IDictionary<string, JToken>` is because the indexer is designed to return null when the key is not found, and also take a null value.

```
var token = someJObject["key"];
// unlike a Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
// token is null if "key" is not a key in the JSON object,
// instead of throwing an exception

// you can also set a particular key as null directly, instead of making a JValue representing "null"
someJObject["key"] = null;
```

`IDictionary<string, JToken>` requires the indexer to be of the non-nullable `JToken` type, so it cannot implement that.