# Null-conditional operators?[] Throwing for data being null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, json.net

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) says

> If `a` evaluates to `null`, the result of `a?.x` or `a?[x]` is `null`.

I want to understand what does **evaluates** mean here. The reason I am asking is that I am getting error for a case mentioned below

```
//Data source for this is mongoDB which supports null type
obj = {"name" : null} 
//MyCode
var Name = obj["name"]?["fullName"]
```

The error I am getting:

> Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.

Comment: If the value for "name" is `null`, then probably obj does not contain any element with such name; thus, the issue is with the child element not present rather than the container (`obj`) being `null`.

Comment: Have you tried `obj?.SelectToken("name").Value<string>()` or `obj?.Value<string>("name")`?

Comment: Depending on your serialization settings, there might not _be_ a property / token with key "name". Can you add those?

Comment: I suspect that the issue is related with the null-conditional operator. Does `obj["name"]` give the same error?

Comment: What is the actual question? How null-conditional works or how Json.Net works? You present two problems here and they aren't really connected besides you use both techniques here. You don't get a NullReferenceException but something else here so accessing a property of a presumably Json.Net type fails. That's independent of you using nullcoallescing or not.

Comment: See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/f4wcgW `obj["name"]` **is not** `null` - it's a `JValue` representing `null` and has no children.

Comment: ^^ Modified version : https://dotnetfiddle.net/fcrMJl - can use some polish, but you get the gist.

Comment: The issue here is very similar to the issue from [Null-coalescing operator returning null for properties of dynamic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29051663/3744182).  Your question is about why null-conditional operators don't work with `null` values in Json.NET and that question is about why null-coalescing operators don't work, but the answer is basically the same -- a non-null `JValue` with `JTokenType.Null` is used for null JSON values by Json.NET.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: See also [Strange behavior in json.net: why is a null JToken replaced with a non-null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51776584) and [Issue with JSON null handling in Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31141527).

Comment: @dbc I think this answers my question

Answer (score 0):

What that tutorial means is: 
If `obj` is null, the result `foo` of the following two statements will both be null.

```cs
var foo = obj?[anyKeyOrIndex];
var foo = obj?.propertyName;
```

But in your case, your `obj` is not null. It is its property `name` that is null. Assuming that you want to read the property `name` from `obj` and the type of this property is either string or null, what you should do is probably:

```cs
string? Name = obj["name"];
```

Comment: what if I am trying obj["name"]["fullName"] and name is explicitly null

Comment: @pr0mpT_07 why don't you deserialize to a (hierarchy of) model class(es) and avoid all this? NewtonSoft could handle all those cases for you.

Comment: @Fildor is that the only way to handle this, my data source is nosql so data can be dynamic, also I prefer using JObject/JToken over poco classes

Comment: No. You could check the `HasChildren` property, e.g. See my comment to the question and linked fiddle @pr0mpT_07

Comment: Correction: `HasValues`